# Titanium Webview iOS not display Yahoo confirm SMS Security

Tags: ios, webview, titanium, titanium-mobile

I try to develop an Application using Yahoo SDK. When App show a webview with url :

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=....
```

Then I input my username and account to login. Then webview displays Confirm SMS security view. But the webview do not display the "verify" button, like the Image below:

[image]

I set following properties to my webview

```
var YahooWebView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
left : 0,
    top : 0,
    right : 0,
    bottom : 0,
    width : 320,
    height : 568,
    scalesPageToFit : true,
    url : "http://example.com"
});
```

How do I resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this, I used yahoo mobile login URL for login and I set the yahoo api URL in "done" parameter. It redirect to yahoo api for app authorization.

```
var authPageURL = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=" + oauthToken;
var yahooMobileLoginUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/m?&.src=oauth&.lang=en-us&.intl=us&.done=" + authPageURL;
YahooWebView.setUrl(yahooMobileLoginUrl);
```